# Can Windows 7 run on Boot Camp with an OCZ Vertex 3 as the boot drive?

Tags: boot-camp

I have looked around, can shed some light, but have failed to get Windows to work.

1. to install Windows the DVD drive MUST stay inside the Mac. It will not work if you have already put it in an enclosure.
2. after you install Windows, you must have a compact flash ready with the Apple Software Update. This holds all the drivers. Or, you can insert the Apple Install disc and install the updates there.
3. after you install the updates, you'll have internet on the Windows partition and you'll have the chance to download the Boot Camp update in Apple Update.
4. this is the last you'll see of Windows functionality. You won't be able to repair or perhaps even boot into it. -- Apple has not been able to address the very very new functionality of the OCZ Vertex 3, among other SSDs (Intel SDDs won't even boot at all).

Has anyone tried, using this mix?

Comment: did you try it  failed, or are you saying you tried something else and are asking if this works?

Comment: I tried, failed, then got it working.